# Xrandr not saving setting

Tags: xorg, xrandr

xrandr at install doesn't detect my TV to be 1920x1080@60hz, so I have to add the setting manually and when I do that with xrandr it works. These are the commands I used:

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 1920x1080
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60
```

When I do that the monitor works great and it's fine and all, problem is whenever I reboot, it goes back to 1360x768 and the mode that I added is not there anymore. I have to add it every time; is there any way to save the settings?

Also how can I set the size of dual monitors?

I am using Fedora 15.

Answer (score 6):

`xrandr` is a tool to modify your X session settings *at runtime*. The `--addmode` option is used to force the Xrandr extension to use an output mode that was not detected at Xorg startup (not save the mode in some configuration file).

It may be that you use `xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 1920x1080` unnecessarily. The Xorg server might detect that mode, but not use it as the default one. To change this, you need to edit your Xorg configuration file: `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (see `man xorg.conf` before you do). There, you can add an option

```
Option "PreferredMode" "your-mode-here"
```

to the `Monitor` section. To know what needs to be put in place of `"your-mode-here"`, you can read `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. Use `less /var/log/Xorg.0.log`, search (by pressing `/`) for a line containing *1920x1080* - it should read something like this:

```
 (II) fglrx(0): Modeline "1920x1080_60.0" 148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz)
```

The part starting with `Modeline` and ending with `vsync` is what you need to copy (select text with mouse) and then paste to the `xorg.conf` under monitor section. Then the use name (`1920x1080_60.0` in the above `ModeLine`) with *"PreferredMode"* option as descibed earlier. You can name it yourself in both places. The important part is that the `ModeLine` has to contain the technical information that Xorg has detected.